# Generate random binary variable conditionally in R

Tags: r, random, binary, conditional-statements, tidyverse

I would like to add an extra column, `z` based on the following conditions:

- if `x == "A"`, generate a binary variable assuming the prob of success (=1) is 0.5
- if `x == "C" & y == "N"`, generate a binary variable assuming the prob of success is 0.25.

```
# Sample data
df <- tibble(
x = ("A", "C", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A"),
y = ("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y"))
```

Currently, my approach uses `filter`, then `set.seed` and `rbinom`, and finally `rbind`. But I am looking for a more elegant solution that doesn't involve subseting and re-joining the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good case for `dplyr::case_when` since you are using `tidyverse` functions.

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df %>% 
  mutate(z = case_when(x == "A" ~ rbinom(n(), 1, 0.5),
                       x == "C" & y == "N" ~ rbinom(n(), 1, 0.25)))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  x     y         z
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 A     Y         0
2 C     N         1
3 C     Y        NA
4 B     N        NA
5 C     N         0
6 A     N         0
7 A     Y         1
```

Comment: rowwise is not necessary here. `rbinom(n(), 1, 0.5)` can get `n()` independent draws in the same time.

Comment: I did not think `n()` could be used in that way, good point!

Comment: Thank you, @Maël. The `mutate` and `case_when` combo is deadly!

Answer (score 2):

You may put your logic into a simple `if / else` structure and wrap it in a function `g()`.

```
g <- \(z) {
  if (z['x'] == 'A') {
    rbinom(1, 1, .5)
  } 
  else if (z['x'] == 'C' & z['y'] == 'N') {
    rbinom(1, 1, .25)
  } else {
    NA
  }
}

set.seed(42)
transform(df, z=apply(df, 1, g))
#   x y  z
# 1 A Y  1
# 2 C N  1
# 3 C Y NA
# 4 B N NA
# 5 C N  0
# 6 A N  1
# 7 A Y  1
```

Comment: Thank you, @jay.sf. Can you explain what the first line (i.e., `\(z) {` does?

Comment: @user15852004 Yes, update your R or if not possible, write `function(z)` instead of `\(z)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try nested `ifelse` like below

```
transform(
    df,
    z = suppressWarnings(
        rbinom(
            nrow(df), 1,
            ifelse(x == "A", 0.5,
                ifelse(x == "C" & y == "N", 0.25, NA)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

which gives

```
  x y  z
1 A Y  1
2 C N  0
3 C Y NA
4 B N NA
5 C N  1
6 A N  1
7 A Y  1
```